# Can't get UISwipeGestureRecognizer to work

Tags: ios, objective-c, swipe

I'm making a sidebar on my app so that when you swipe right it opens, I am using this code in the object I made called sidebar:

```
_swipeRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self.superview action:@selector(swiped)];

[_swipeRecognizer setDirection: UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight];

[self.superview addGestureRecognizer:_swipeRecognizer];
```

And this of course crashes and throws the error:

```
[UIView swiped]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1fdbd0c0
```

because it's looking for the "swiped" method on self.superview when I want it to look for the method on self, but I want the gesture to be detected on self.superview.

I'm also confused, if I set initWithTarget then why do I have to do addGestureRecognizer? What's the difference between those two things?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this:

```
_swipeRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self.superview action:@selector(swiped)];
```

to:

```
_swipeRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swiped)];
```

The call to `initWithTarget:action:` specifies the class that gets told about the gesture events. The "target" must implement the "action" method.

The call to `addGestureRecognizer:` specifies which view the gesture must happen on.

In many cases these are the same but in your case they are different.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to handle the gesture recognized in `self`, at first line, you should set `self` as the the receiver, not self.superview:

```
_swipeRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swiped)];
```

then implement the `swiped` action:

```
-(void)swiped:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
//enter code here
}
```